# Enclosed return value and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have ran out of ideas dealing with this nested return situation. 
I am trying to find out if the array retrieven from the backend via a promise contains an element in the array.
This works:

```
    function isNameTaken() {
            var duplicateFound = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entities.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.entities[i].name === $scope.myName) {
                    duplicateFound = 1;
                }
            }
        return duplicateFound;
    }
```

I'd like to adjust this so there is a refresh of the array before the comparison. I have a method for retrieving it that resolves into a promise. Now, I can wrap the whole thing into a .then wrap but I then cannot access my duplicateFound variable from outside to the the async nature of the inner function.

This what I want to get working:

```
    function isNameTaken() {
        return loadEntities().$promise.then(function(entities) {    
            var duplicateFound = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
                if (entities[i].name === $scope.myName) {
                    duplicateFound = 1;
                }
            }
        return duplicateFound;
        });
    }
```

The inner part works flawlessly as the promise resolves, but the function as a whole always resolves to true as the `return loadEntities()` part does not pass me back the value of my enclosed return inside but the promise itself. And without it, it always resolves to false(I think its an undefined).

So in short. The first one works. How do I get my hands on the value of `duplicateFound` outside this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function as a whole always resolves to true

No, it does not return `true`. It does return a promise for a boolean value, which *might* fulfill with `true` (or with `false` or reject altogether). That promise of course is a truthy value, so you cannot use it right inside of an `if` condition.

Instead, you have to adapt the calling code to anticipate the promise, and let it wait for the resolution before inspecting the value. Of course, this makes your whole function (and everything that calls it) asynchronous.

```
return isNameTaken().then(function(taken) {
    if (taken)
        …
    else
        …
}); // yields another promise for the result of the callback
```

Comment: Wow. Nothing short of magic man, and I know a thing or two about promises, having worked with protractor and already endured some headaches. You are right its just truthy, I didn't think of modifying the calling function, because I was dead set on the returns not working properly. :D

Comment: Since the protractor(jasmine) 'expect' functions did the resolving for me automatically, I was not used to thinking as a whole going down the call chain. Thanks again, with this added I learned a great deal today about promises and nested returns, that appears I was doing correctly the whole time.

Comment: "*appears I was doing correctly the whole time*" - yes indeed. You were doing well on that - missing `return`s are one of the more common mistakes :-)